# What does 得られる mean here?

Tags: meaning

> シャ－カ－ン殿はファティマの碧玉…… そしてそれによって得られるファティマの至宝を狙っております。

From the context, Shakhan(シャ－カ－ン) needs "Fatima Jasper"(ファティマの碧玉) to get "Fatima Treasure"(ファティマの至宝), but hasn't acquired it yet.

So would it be

> "...by means of it he is aiming to obtain  the treasure  of
>   Fatima."

or

> "...by means of it he'll be given the opportunity to aim for the treasure of Fatima."

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ファティマの碧玉 and ファティマの至宝 are both direct objects of the verb 狙う. それによって得られる is a relative clause that modifies ファティマの至宝.

- シャ－カ－ン殿はファティマの碧玉を狙っております。
- そして、シャ－カ－ン殿は（それによって得られる→）ファティマの至宝を狙っております。

So the former is closer to the original Japanese sentence.

> シャ－カ－ン殿はファティマの碧玉…… そしてそれによって得られるファティマの至宝を狙っております。
>
> - Shakhan is aiming to obtain *a)* Fatima Jasper, and *b)* the treasure of Fatima which he can get by obtaining Fatima Jasper.
> - Shakhan is aiming to obtain Fatima Jasper, and by extention, the treasure of Fatima.